# How do I redirect after login to another page in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js and wondering how i can redirect to another pages when a client is logged in

```
user ? (Redirect exact path="/Study")
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Comment: check out the useHistory hook

Comment: Please be more specific, add some examples, or if possible add some sandbox to check out what are you up to. In that case maybe someone can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using React Router you can do something like

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(()=>{
  if(user){
    history.push('/otherRoute');
  }
}, [user])
```

and then just `setUser` to the user when you handle the login, or do something like

```
  <Route
    render={() => (!user ? <Something/> : <Redirect to="/Study" />)}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is quite broad and is a bit difficult to answer correctly. It depends a bit if you are using some routing-library or not. Then you might have different routing recommendations made available by your selected router.

But if we assume we do not have any router-library and just want to have some state and when it changes we change our url to something different we could approach it as follows.

> Full working example([Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-borg-432db?file=/src/App.tsx))

```
import { memo, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  // State to save current user, default to "undefined"
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  // Inline Login-button component
  const Login = memo(() => (
    <button onClick={() => setUser({ username: "user1" })}>Sign in</button>
  ));

  // In use effect we listen any changes to User-state object with dependency array
  useEffect(() => {
    // On initial render user does not exist return early
    if (!user) return;
    // If user exists we push new browser history-state. You might want to have more specific check if certain key/value exists.
    // args (state, title, route)
    window.history.pushState(null, "Redirected Page", "/new_page");
    // Artificial page-reload to update window.location-object
    window.location.reload();
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Login />
      <a href="/">Frontpage</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can follow same pattern but use your router-library route/redirection -function as stated in the documentation.